# Is there a sect in Islam that follows the the Quran to the exclusion of hadith?

Tags: quran, hadith, sects

In christianity protestants are [Sola scriptura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sola_scriptura).

Is there a similar muslim group who follow the same kind of belief that the Quran is all that needed, and disregard other texts (such as Hadith)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are called [Quranists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quranism). They are not one sect but individuals following the ideology that Qur'an is sufficient. [Ghulam Ahmed Pervez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghulam_Ahmed_Pervez) (1903-1985) and Abdullah Chakralawi (d: 1930) have been main proponents and pioneers of this view in Indian Subcontinent. Their books are written in Urdu language and can be found [here](http://ebooks.rahnuma.org/religion.html).